# Putting RUN commands in one line make build faster?

Tags: docker

In my docker file, does it really matter if I put `RUN` commands in one line or not? Does putting them in one line make build time faster?

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends python3
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends open-vm-tools
```

vs.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends python3
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends open-vm-tools
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By minimizing the number of layers you're reducing the size of your image and yes, also build time. This is also recommended in [best practices section "Minimize number of layers"](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

> In older versions of Docker, it was important that you minimized the number of layers in your images to ensure they were performant. The following features were added to reduce this limitation.
>
> - Only the instructions RUN, COPY, ADD create layers. Other instructions create temporary intermediate images, and do not increase the size of the build.
>
> ...

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking, the build- and run-time cost of having one RUN command vs. several will be imperceptible, and I wouldn't try to optimize here solely in the name of performance.

In the specific example you show, a couple of things are true:

- The Debian APT tool on its own has a non-trivial startup time; and separate from one RUN command vs. several, one `apt-get install` vs. two will be faster.

  ```sh
  RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 open-vm-tools
  ```
- Debian and Ubuntu update their repositories fairly frequently, and when they do, package links that were in last week's `apt-get update` stop working.  Meanwhile, Docker layer caching will try to avoid re-running a step that it's already run.  If you did build your image a week ago, Docker will say "I already did this `RUN apt-get update` and so I don't need to run it again"; but that means it's cached a stale package index.  **It's important to run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in the same RUN step.**

  ```sh
  RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 open-vm-tools
  ```

And in general:

- If you have some cleanup steps you want to run, it's important to run them in the same RUN step.  This sequence creates a layer after the build step, and so the `RUN rm` step doesn't actually make the final layer smaller.

  ```sh
  # All of this example should be combined into a single RUN step
  RUN tar xzf package-1.2.3.tar.gz
  RUN cd package-1.2.3 && ./configure && make && make install
  # There is a layer here including the build tree
  RUN rm -rf package-1.2.3
  ```
- If you're iterating on a Dockerfile, it can be easier to split things out into many small RUN commands while you're debugging, and combine them later.  That's perfectly fine and you should get an identical tree at the end.

  ```sh
  # I'm trying to figure out the configure options so I might
  RUN tar xzf package-1.2.3.tar.gz
  RUN cd package-1.2.3 && ./configure --some-option
  RUN cd package-1.2.3 && make
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't clean the apt cache at the end of your "one liner" you are actually not achieving a lot. A big layer is still added to your image.

The main idea is to put all the installations on one line and end that line with a cleanup, so that when docker saves that layer (before moving on to the next command) it only saves the newly installed software without all the downloads and cache that are not used anymore anyway.

As for the speed probably you gain a little with writing more on 1 line but I don't think it is that much. Of course if you have hundreds of them then you would see a difference.